# Why a vector of column names can't be used to filter rows in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data `dt` and a vector of column names `cols`

```
dt <- data.table(id = letters[1:10], amount = 1:10, id2 = c(rep('a',5),rep('b',5)))
cols <- 'id'
```

Can someone help me to understand why this approach not works

```
dt[cols=='a']
```

but this one works?

```
dt[get(cols)=='a']
```

Both approachs shouldn't return the same thing in `vec`?

Comment: Do you need a logical vector as output

Comment: To me, `cols == "a"` is always going to fail since you are explicitly checking the contents of `cols` against the literal `"a"`. If `c(cols == "a")` makes sense (as false) that you are comparing a variable against a literal, why does your assumption of what will happen changing inside of `dt`? The fact that `cols` contains what might be interpreted as column names is something you *know* but is dangerous for a package to *infer*. Ergo `get(.)`. Or `..cols`. Or a few other ways that are *explicit* in you telling the `data.table` package what you intend.

Comment: @r2evans I was thinking it would understand as `dt[id=='a']` since `cols=id` so it would be a logical vector and should works. Thanks for the information.

Comment: But you're assuming that `data.table::[` will *know* to look *inside* of `cols` to see the contents and interpret those as meaningful in that context. In most cases, when I see `dt[cols=="a"]` (whether `data.table` or not), the assumption is that `cols` is either the name of a column (`data.table` or `tibble`, using non-standard evaluation) or a variable visible in the current environment. Either way, it's checking the contents of `cols` against the literal, with no assumption that it should get the contents and then get *those* contents. that's not a safe assumption/inference.

Comment: You can also do a fast binary search: `dt["a", on = cols]` (subset as join).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could `eval`uate on a `sym`bol

```
 dt[eval(as.name(cols)) == 'a']
   id amount id2
1:  a      1   a
```

Or specify the `.SDcols`

```
dt[dt[, .SD[[1]] == 'a', .SDcols = cols]]
 id amount id2
1:  a      1   a
```

Or directly subset `.SD` if there is a single column

```
dt[dt[, .SD[[cols]] == 'a']]
   id amount id2
1:  a      1   a
```

---

The preferred method would be through `.SDcols` as `get` can sometimes have env issues, while `eval` (not so recommended by the community)

Answer (score 7):

[Akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) has already offered a helpful [*solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642284) to your problem, so I will offer the **diagnosis**.

## Filtering a `data.table`

To filter `dt` as you intend, `data.table` needs an **entire vector** of **ten** `logical` values, corresponding to the ten rows in `dt`, to indicate which of the rows to keep (`TRUE`) and which to discard (`FALSE`).  So when you filter `dt`, you must include such a logical vector (or something that evaluates to it) within the `[` brackets. Here is an artificial example:

```
dt[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)]
```

This would give us the filtered results in the following `data.table`:

```
   id amount id2
1:  a      1   a
2:  d      4   a
3:  e      5   a
4:  g      7   b
```

## Why `cols` Fails

Since `cols` has a `character` value of `'id'`

```
cols <- 'id'
```

then comparing `cols == 'a'` is the same as comparing `'id' == 'a'`, which is obviously `FALSE`:

```
dt[cols == 'a']
# ...is the same as...
dt['id' == 'a']
# ...is the same as...
dt[FALSE]
```

This provides only a *single* `logical` value (`FALSE`), rather than the *vector* of *ten* `logical` values that `data.table` really needs for filtering.

The result is a `data.table` that omits *everything*

```
Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): id,amount,id2
```

in contrast to `dt[TRUE]`, which *includes* everything:

```
    id amount id2
 1:  a      1   a
 2:  b      2   a
 3:  c      3   a
 4:  d      4   a
 5:  e      5   a
 6:  f      6   b
 7:  g      7   b
 8:  h      8   b
 9:  i      9   b
10:  j     10   b
```

## Why `get(cols)` Works

When you use `get('my_variable')`, you are telling R to "get" the value of `my_variable` from the surrounding environment.  If you run `get()` within the `[` operation on `dt`

```
dt[get(# ...
   ]
```

R will search within `dt` for a column by the given name, and it will return that column (a vector) as the value for `get()`. So using `get('id')` in this context will give you the column `id` in `dt`, which is the vector

```
c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j')
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Now we put it all together:

```
dt[get(cols) == 'a')
# ...is the same as...
dt[get('id') == 'a')
# ...is the same as...
dt[c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j') == 'a']
# ...is the same as...
dt[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)]
```

This gives us the filtered results in the following `data.table`:

```
   id amount id2
1:  a      1   a
```